# Python 3D image segmentation find local peaks in distance map for watershed

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing, scipy, scikit-image

I am trying to segment 3d tomographs of porous networks in python. I am able to calculate the distance map with `ndimage.distance_transform_edt` and the peaks with `feature.peak_local_max`. when I apply the watershed algorithm a get an acceptable result, but the markers of the peaks are not located at the visible peaks, see image, of the distance map

Thanks in advance

[image]

Here the code a is the image

```
D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a)
localMax = feature.peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=50,
            labels=a)
localMax2 = feature.peak_local_max(D, indices=True, min_distance=50,
            labels=a)

markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3,3,3)))[0]
labels = morphology.watershed(-D,markers,mask=a)
```

Comment: What is the question?Also, please include your code, see [mcve].

Comment: is there a other option to calculate local minima for 3d arrays?

Comment: (a) as Cris mentioned, please provide a complete code example; but (b), yes, see `skimage.morphology.local_maxima`, which is the recommended way of computing them if you don't need the fancy `min_distance` features of `peak_local_max`.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way:

i had to exclude the borders and apply a threshold

```
     D = ndimage.distance_transform_edt(a)

    localMax = feature.peak_local_max(D, indices=False, min_distance=30,
        labels=a,threshold_abs=9,exclude_border=1)
    localMax2 = feature.peak_local_max(D, indices=True, min_distance=30,
        labels=a,threshold_abs=9,exclude_border=1)

    #markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3,3,3)))[0]
    markers = ndimage.label(localMax, structure=np.ones((3,3,3)))[0]
    labels = morphology.watershed(-D,markers,mask=a)
    regions=measure.regionprops(labels,intensity_image=a)
```